# Suspend UI Layouts in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I have a bunch of code in a routine that looks a bit like this:

```
a.setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
textview t1 = (TextView) a.findViewById(R.id.mylayout_t1);
t1.setText("Hello")
t1.setTypeface(font);
t1.setTextColor(colour);
t1.setTextSize(fontSize);

textview t2 = (TextView) a.findViewById(R.id.mylayout_t2);
t2.setText("Hello Again")
t2.setTypeface(font);
t2.setTextColor(colour);
t2.setTextSize(fontSize);
```

The problem I'm having is that before when the routine is called, the layout is done with all the fonts at the default font/size/colour and then they quickly change to the specified values, which is not very pleasant on the eye.

Is there some kind of command I can add to the beginning of the routine to suspend any layout, and then another command to resume at the end of the routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1) Put your all code (you mentioned above) in `onCreate()` method and at last call `t1.setVisible(true);`

2) Put your code in the method in which you are creating your UI (like `initUI()` or something like that) and call this method before setting visibility to true.

Comment: thanks, what I ended up doing, rather than setting the controls visibility to false, then true individually, I set the base layout to be invisible in xml, and after all the settings were applied, I set the base layout to be visible in code.

Comment: Does your screen go blank when you set your layout's visibility to false? If this is happening you can also try some fade out animation to avoid black screen..

Comment: @shraddha I have similar question. What is the general approach? I have 50 views in a RelativeLayout which all of them are aligned together. I need to change their LayoutParams programmatically. How can I suspend layout operations temporarily, and finally perform them at once? Is it enough to make them invisible and then visible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using XML to set the text style instead of doing it programmaticly. See [this Android Dve Guide page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) for more on this topic.

Another (bad?) way might be to use XML to set the views visibility to false and when you have made your style changes, call `t1.setVisibility(true)`. Haven't tried this one, so it might produce a similar, unwanted result.

Comment: trouble with XML is (if I remember correctly) you can't set custom fonts?